# Request Error (invalid_request) - Android Browser

Tags: html, http, request

I have a basic Jetty server running locally. If I pull up http://localhost/servlet1 in a web browser on my desktop, I am able to see proper content (basic html page). However, when I navigate to this site in the Android Emulator (2.2), I get the following error:

> Request Error (invalid_request) Your
>   request could not be processed.
>
> Request could not be handled This
>   could be caused by a misconfiguration,
>   or possibly a malformed request.
>
> For assistance, contact your network
>   support team.

Any idea what the issue might be? I'm afraid to move on if this basic task doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the nature of the network stack in the emulator, you can't use "localhost" or 127.0.0.1 to connect to the host computer.  Try using 10.0.2.2 instead, so: http://10.0.2.2/servlet1

From http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=133:

> 127.0.0.1 is the emulated system's own loopback interface, not the one
>   running on your host development
>   machine.
>
> within the Android system, one should
>   use 10.0.2.2 which is an alias
>   specifically setup to contact your
>   host 127.0.0.1